# Composite index with single varchar column vs multiple varchar column

Tags: database, oracle, indexing, relational-database

I have a use case where I want to create a composite index. I have two options for creating the composite index.

> Option 1: STATUS_CODE (varchar(1)) & TICKET_ID (number)
>
> Option 2: STAUS (varchar(50)) & TICKET_ID (number)

For STATUS and STATUS_CODE I have only 5 possible values.

Which one will be better option for my composite index? Will there be any performance difference between these two indexes?

Comment: ticket_id looks like a key of some kind - does it already have an index? You may find that your composite index is ignored because STATUS is not very selective (5 values)

Comment: @NevilleKuyt - Both ticket_id and status_code look like keys of some kind; this table is probably a "fact" table, where each ticket is shown with a status. (It may also be a historical table - showing "ticket" and "status" history, with an as-of date column as well. The composite index MAY be used, even if STATUS is not very selective; for example, if one queries for all tickets that are in status "on hold" - simply because ALL the data is already in the composite index, so a table scan would not be needed.

Comment: @mathguy you are correct. There can be 99% values in C or COMPLETED. I will try to retrieve only the values which are in HOLD or some other status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If everything else is the same, then the first option is better. Each row will be represented by less data in the index, which will allow the index to take less space on disk. This way, whenever the index is used, more data (from the index) can be retrieved from disk in a single physical read operation. How much this affects performance, though, will depend on how much data you have in the first place, and on how long the STATUS values are. (If they are all close to 50 characters, then it will make a bigger difference; not so much if most of them are very short.)

It seems, though, that your table design violates Third Normal Form. If STATUS_CODE and STATUS determine each other, this means that you should have a separate table just for "status" (showing codes and descriptions). Your big table should only have the STATUS_CODE column, not the STATUS column.

Comment: Thanks for the details. Basically I am going to create a new table and add index. Just for purpose of explanation I had two values STATUS and STATUS_CODE. I am going to have only one column.